# Check if input is selected

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div class="radio" id="uniform-L1"><span><input type="radio" name="length" class="radio" value="L1" id="L1"></span></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
if(document.getElementById('L1').checked) {
         console.log("chwer");
        }
 </script>
```

I tried to find what's wrong with my JS but I couldn't. I have no console errors.

Comment: You might need to start with JS and html basics. https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp. The script you added it just loads once when the page loads. You need to call the function everytime you check/uncheck the radio button

Comment: @evolutionxbox you can use .checked on a radio button

Comment: @MrJami don't mind me. Just forgetting my radio input basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the `change` event if you want to log `"chwer"` everytime the radio button is checked:

```js
document.getElementById('L1').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("chwer");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="radio" id="uniform-L1"><span><input type="radio" name="length" class="radio" value="L1" id="L1"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the node with `querySelector`

```js
function checkSelection() {
    const input = document.querySelector('input[name="length"]');
    if (input.checked) {
        console.log(input.value);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="radio" id="uniform-L1">
    <input type="radio" name="length" class="radio" value="L1" id="L1"> Radio
</div>
<button onclick="checkSelection()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that when your run your JS that would only check to see if the radio button is checked when it loads(which wouldn't be checked). If you want the JS to activate when the radio button changed you'll have to activate an [onclick](https://careerkarma.com/blog/javascript-onclick/) to check when your button has changed and then run the script.